# Is there a java equivalent to OpenSSL's bn_rand_range?

Tags: java, android, security, openssl

Specifically, I just want to generate a cryptographically secure random number between 0 and some number *x*.

In OpenSSL this is done with the function `bn_range`.

I can implement it myself using Java's `BigInteger(int bits, Random r)` constructor (which generates a number from 0 to 2<sup>bits</sup>). But I would like, if possible, to use a better tested algorithm for the sake of security.

Is there a standard way to do this in Java?

P.S. I am actually using Android, but I don't know how to do it in standard Java.

EDIT: *x* is a large integer stored as a `BigInteger`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, this functionality is not provided. But it is easy enough to implement yourself.

```
Random r = new SecureRandom();    
BigInteger q = something_big;
BigInteger ans;

do
    ans = BigInteger(bits_in_q, r);
while (ans.compareTo(q) >= 0); // bn_rand_range generates numbers < q
```

Answer (score 3):

Java provides a subclass of the `Random` class, the [SecureRandom](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html) class. The description includes:

> This class provides a cryptographically strong random number generator (RNG). Many implementations are in the form of a pseudo-random number generator (PRNG), which means they use a deterministic algorithm to produce a pseudo-random sequence from a true random seed. Other implementations may produce true random numbers and yet others may use a combination of both techniques

Java provides just one implementation, the `SHA1PRNG` function, which it [details](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/security/CryptoSpec.html#AppA) as a pseudo-random number generation (PRNG) algorithm:

> This implementation follows the IEEE P1363 standard, Appendix G.7: "Expansion of source bits", and uses SHA-1 as the foundation of the PRNG. It computes the SHA-1 hash over a true-random seed value concatenated with a 64-bit counter which is incremented by 1 for each operation. From the 160-bit SHA-1 output, only 64 bits are used.

It should also be noted that the `bn_rand_range` function from OpenSSL is also [considered](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/BN_rand.html#DESCRIPTION) to use a pseudo-random number generation (PRNG) algorithm, though I could not find details as for to what algorithm the function implements.

Because `SecureRandom` is a subclass of the `Random` class, `SecureRandom` objects can use all the methods of `Random` including the `.nextInt(int n)` method. The `nextInt` method provides:

> Returns a pseudorandom, uniformly distributed int value between 0 (inclusive) and the specified value (exclusive), drawn from this random number generator's sequence.

Therefore, to generate a cryptography strong pseudo-random number in the range of (0,100] you can use code like the following:

```java
import java.security.SecureRandom;
class secure{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        SecureRandom random = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
        System.out.println(random.nextInt(100));
    }
}
```

Comment: I am already using SecureRandom in my implementation of bn_rand_range in java. The question is, is there an implementation of a function that behaves like bn_rand_range,  not bn_rand.

Comment: I've updated the answer to show the code to mimic bn_rand_range. You mentioned finding a number between 0 and X, so I just used nextInt. If you wanted a range between X and Y, you would use `random.nextInt(Y-X)+X`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention X is not an int, but rather a BigInteger. Otherwise your approach would be exactly what I am looking for.