# Result is not random in Android

Tags: java, android, encryption, private-key

I am implementing an encryption algorithm which uses large numbers, so while making a java application I have to use the class BigInteger.

However, when I tried to implement the same in an android application the constructor

```
public BigInteger(int bitLength,int certainty,Random rnd),
```

no random BigInteger is generated (The same integer is generated again and again 35879 :P) . A random BigInteger is generated successfully in a simple java Application.

For a reference,

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#constructor_detail

Also, Please tell me if I import something of the form java.util.* , is it expected to work in any android application ??

**Please make your comments if Android does not support BigInteger or any other class exists similar to that which is supported ???**

Here the method systemoutprintln() is used for printing the respective string to a layout.

Here is a code for your reference,

```
public class keyGenerator {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */

  static  Vector check = new Vector();


  static protected BigInteger p= new BigInteger("161");
  static protected BigInteger q= new BigInteger("47");
  static protected Random s =new Random();
  static protected BigInteger n = new BigInteger("1");
  static protected BigInteger trails;
  static protected BigInteger lambda ;
  static protected BigInteger nsq  = new BigInteger("1");
  static protected BigInteger g = new BigInteger("1");
  static protected BigInteger temp = new BigInteger("1");
  static protected long timetkn;
  static protected View myview;
  static protected String[] printarray = new String[1000];
  static protected int ii=0;

static protected int maxbit;
private static BigInteger two = new BigInteger("2");

public keyGenerator() {

  //  Activity activity = new Activity();
// et.append("Second Part!!");
// EditText et = (EditText)activity.findViewById(R.string.second);
//    et.append("Working");


    long keyStart = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    p = new BigInteger(7,1,s);

            Systemoutprintln("Assumed p :" +p.toString());
  /*  while(!isPrime(p) && ( (p.compareTo(two)==1) || (p.compareTo(two))==0) )
    {
            p = new BigInteger(7,1,s);

    Systemoutprintln(p.toString());
    }*/


    Systemoutprintln("Assumed q :" +p.toString());
    q = new BigInteger(7,1,s);
```

Comment: You should focus in the `Random` object (the BigDecimal does nothing else than wrap it) to check its behavior.

Comment: You should probably use `SecureRandom` for cryptography purposes.

Comment: On what kind of device do you get these results? On an emulator maybe?

Comment: @owlstead its a Galaxy Nexus S cellphone with 4.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work, according to the java docs on [Random numbers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#Random%28%29). However, I am noticing that you are printing the bigInteger p twice, with two different labels. Is it remotely possible that you are mixing them up?

EDIT: With some help from digitaljoel, I found this prior quest:

[Is there a java equivalent to OpenSSL's bn_rand_range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9441598/is-there-a-java-equivalent-to-openssls-bn-rand-range)

Essentially, you should use SecureRandom, and use the method given there, namely:

```
Random r = new SecureRandom();    
BigInteger q = something_big;
BigInteger ans;

do
    BigInteger(bits_in_q, r);
while (ans > q)
```

Comment: okay thanks thats a mistake!! . but still there is a problem with random numbers , it is printing the same p again and again.

Comment: @pearsonphoto it looks as if the random function is actually deterministic !! It gives a different set of numbers everytime i call the constructor function, but the list is same. meaning you will always get the same first number , same second number and so on....

Comment: @pearsonphoto and digitaljoel !! you deserve credit for your solution, nut please extend it a little bit for me. AS PER THE REQUIREMENT OF THE ALGORITHM, I NEED A PRIME NUMBER. by including certainty, I was sure that in nearly most cases, the number is prime. 

If i create an explicit method for checking if the number is prime and adding it in the while condition of the loop, it is expected to take a good amount of time which I dont want. Please tell me how can I get a "Probably prime" random number. And SecureRandom does not work when certainty is introduced :(

Comment: @rajatIIT: That wasn't in your original question. I would start a new one to ask that question, it's quite a bit different than what you asked for... There are quite a few tricks to making sure the number is prime and making it work quickly, however.

Comment: I am a newbie to both cryptography and android. Please provide me some link or topic related to the tricks.

Comment: Just ask a new question, and post the link here.

Answer (score 3):

If you look at [the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/math/BigInteger.html) you will see that the rand argument in the constructor you are calling is unused.

`Implementation Note: the Random argument is ignored. This implementation uses OpenSSL's bn_rand as a source of cryptographically strong pseudo-random numbers.`

Perhaps remove it and supply null as the argument, or remove the certainty argument, in which case it will use your Random object (according to the docs.)

Comment: @digitaljeol I understand that it is mentioned in the docs, but the problem remains the same, if i pass null as a parameter. and i cant remove the certainty as it is demand of the algorithm that p and q be prime See @ paillier cryptosystem.

Comment: Interesting. Note from the `bn_rand` docs, you need to seed the PRNG before the function should be used. It seems that the PRNG was not correctly seeded before use. This *could* be a pretty important bug.